# Can't submit a form via jquery on clicking anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php

So i was making a dynamic sidebar menu, and when i click the anchor tag i wanted to submit the form and redirect me to the search result page  using jquery. but the anchor tag doesn't seem to do anything when clicked.

```
<?php foreach ($schedule as $d) { ?>
    <form id="form1" class="ml-12" action="article/search" method="post">
        <li aria-haspopup="true" class="menu-item">
            <input type="hidden" name="param" value="<?php echo $d->title; ?>"> 
            <a class="menu-link" id="month"><i class="menu-bullet menu-bullet-dot"><span></span></i><span class="menu-text" id="month"><?php echo $d->title; ?></span></a>                                                                      
        </li>
    </form>                                                 
<?php } ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#month").click(function(){
                $("#form1").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

can you guys tell me what i did wrong ?

Comment: An `id` needs to be unique in a document. You have two elements with the `id` `month` for every item in your `$schedule` and also `form1` repeats for every iteration of your `foreach`.

Comment: Oooow so because i was looping the form and the id="month" so there are more than one id element with the same id right ?

Comment: FYI, `li` as direct child of `form` is also invalid HTML.

Comment: @Malik Right. And `$("#month")` will only select one single element. (Generally the first one it finds.)